# MVC 4 , how to retrieve dropdown list from stored procedure through list of object

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have to retrieve through procedure from database a dropdown which have project name... Which contain a method which is able to convert `Datatable` to list of objects and then return list and hold that list to the drop down

My function

```
public static List<Object> convertDataTableToObject(Object ob, DataTable datatable)
{
        List<Object> obj = ob as List<object>;

        foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
        {
            obj.Add(dr);
        }

        return obj;
}
```

I called that function

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so we know where to start?

Comment: ok..
        public static List<Object> convertDataTableToObject(Object ob, DataTable datatable)
        {
            List<Object> obj = ob as List<object>;
            foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
            {
                obj.Add(dr);
            }

            return obj;
        }

Comment: this is my function ...ok where i am passing data table and object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your returned data contains fields that represent your selectlist Text and Value, you can do this:

```
var MySelectList = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (DataRow dr in datatable.Rows)
{
     MySelectList.Add(new SelectListItem(Text = dr.Text, Value=dr.Value);
}
return MySelectList;
```

Comment: what will be the return type of this function

Comment: This is only for dropdown Iff i want a common method then how can I

Comment: I thought you wanted a dropdownlist? I'm not sure what you mean when you say 'common method'

Comment: Common method means i have many form contain some textboxes,ok and also jqgrids and when i click on that grid link ,it will check the databse the id of that link and retrive that and assign in text boxes.

Comment: So for retrival i want a common method for retrival as a object list rather than a datatable so i can assign them to textboxes in MVC4